# How to fire code only when script.js is ran via node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `script.js` that I either use on client side html page. Either via nodejs.

**How can I get a function to fire only if the script is run via nodejs ?**

Comment: Check for something that should only exist in the browser (document) or node (exports). This is how underscore does it https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L45-L55

Answer (score 1):

[**Queue.js**](https://github.com/mbostock/queue/blob/master/queue.js#L77-L79) handles it such:

```
if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) define(function() { return queue; });
else if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) module.exports = queue;
else this.queue = queue;
```

[**Underscore**](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L45-L55) does something such :

```
  if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
      exports = module.exports = _;
    }
    exports._ = _;
  } else {
    root._ = _;
  }
```

**But** this seems to assess node.modules. Secondly, if someone could confirm what each case is, that would help !

Answer (score 1):

[fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) has a useful one-liner:

```
var isLikelyNode = typeof Buffer !== 'undefined' && typeof window === 'undefined';
```

Comment: None of the answers solved my case. Indeed, i am creating a virtual windows via jsdom, so my js script always is in a browser, real or virtual. I haven t tested these answers for strickly serverside use cases. So i can neither valid your, nor my answer. But I can +1 some of your answer so you get to 2000 points :)